# Finding the value of k that satisfies the discrimant

Tags: discriminant

I am struggling to do this question

> Find the valus of $k$ so that $kx^2-2+kx+x=0$  has discriminant $Δ= -24$

I tried to use the formula $b^2-4ac$ but my answer is completely wrong.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: $b^2-4ac=-24$ to see we get $$k^2+10k+25=0$$ solve this to find k

Comment: Thanks this method produces the correct answer. However how did you get to 10k

Comment: $-24=b^2-4ac$ implies $-24=(k+1)^2-4(k)(-2)=k^2+2k+1+8k$ so we get $$k^2+10k+1=-24$$

Comment: Oh I see thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$$kx^2-2+kx+x=0\implies kx^2+(k+1)x-2=0$$
Then solve for: $b^2-4ac=-24$ for $a=k,b=k+1,c=-2$